# How to efficiently input matrices in Mathematica (compared to what MATLAB offers)

Tags: matrix, syntax, customization, matlab

Every time I want to manually input a matrix in *Mathematica*, it takes me a while since every new row has to be in a separate pair of curly braces.

For instance:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

In MATLAB, this is solved more concisely by using a semicolon to indicate a new row:

```
a=[1 2; 3 4]
```

It is much faster to type.

Can one built a function that automatically replaces the semicolon by a bracket, such that typing becomes faster?

```
[1 2; 3 4] // someFunction
(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} *)
```

Comment: More info is needed. Are all elements of the matrix integers?, are all matrices rectangular?

Comment: I assure you its only a question of getting used to it!

Comment: @Feyre For arbitrairy Matrices. Put all that is before the smi-colum into a curly bracet and replace the square bracets also with curly bracets.

Comment: This also annoys me, even though I use Mathematica very often.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/InputAMatrix.html, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TypingMatrices.html, and http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EnteringTablesAndMatrices.html

Comment: Related:  [(761)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/761/121), [(7836)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7836/121), [(55990)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55990/121)

Comment: if it is really easier and you gind enough others which think the same way it is maybe instead of programming such a thing by yourself more worth to ask the developers of mathematica if they can/will change it to fit your needs, if no one else thinks the same way as you do then you should ask yourself why you are the only one having a problem with this

Comment: I think "faster to code" is often not efficient in terms of code execution. When is a code "efficient"?

Comment: So far, nothing I've seen here beats Ctrl-comma etc, not even Matlab.  Mainly because, one can input *Mathematica* expression with Ctrl-comma.  If you're talking about a large amount of data entry, I'd use something else to enter it other than Mathematica or Matlab.

Comment: @konqui Do you find it more enjoyable to put those curly bracets around each row ?

Comment: @DoHe to be honest yes the curly braces i use this much so i instinctively know where they are but the square ones i always have to search

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quick-n-dirty. I dispense with open/close bracket, trivial to put in if it matters:

```
fn = ToExpression/@ImportString[StringReplace[#, ";" -> "\n"], "Table"] &;

mymat = "2 4;  3 4 5 ; 5 6" // fn
mymat2 = "a b;2 c; d 5" // fn
```

> {{2, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {5, 6}}
>
> {{a, b}, {2, c}, {d, 5}}

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Instead of `StringReplace` you can use `"LineSeparators"` option for `ImportString`: `ToExpression@ImportString[#, "Table", "LineSeparators" -> ";"] &`

Comment: @SimonRochester - ah, nice. I import/export about as often as total solar eclipses, don't know all the options off top-of-head. +1

Answer (score 10):

You can make use of the build-in palettes e.g. the `Basic Math Assistant`. The major advantages are

- `MatrixForm`-esque look for input
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> can be used to fill the matrix from top left to bottom right.
- 2D-Navigation using arrow keys is also possible.
- Hotkeys for adding rows and columns

[image: gif]

Comment: Thanks for the answere, but I am afraid, this still takes more time than simply typing [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] and it takes a  lot of space when the Matrix is very large. (20*20 etc. )

Comment: How often does one need to manually input $20 \times 20$ matrices? If I had to do this a significant number of times I would outsource the task to [amazon mechanical turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome)

Comment: (+1) I do this with Ctrl-comma and Ctrl-return and tab between entries. Parentheses are optional. -- Probably what you meant by "Hotkeys," but the palette, imo, is an unnecessary inconvenience once you have the workflow down.

Comment: Move-aim-click for each new column and row is even slower than just typing all the braces. And using `<Ctrl>-,` and `<Ctrl>-<Return>` is really fast.

Answer (score 9):

```
m = Function[expr, Block[{Times = List, CompoundExpression = List}, expr], HoldAll];
m[b a; c d e]
(*{{b, a}, {c, d, e}}*)
```

Do notice this representation has conspicuous limitation e.g. it can not be used to represent `{{a b}, {c, d e}}`. It doesn't cause trouble in MATLAB because MATLAB doesn't have implicit time sign.

Also, it can't represent `{i = 1; i + 1}`. MATLAB suffers this problem, too.

Comment: ok, but you can *only* do symbolic calculations this way. `m[2 1; 3 4 5]` obviously doesn't work.

Comment: @Feyre Are you sure?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw8EM.png Notice the existence of `HoldAll`.

Comment: You're right, I remember a similar question and this failing, but you're right. It had to do with representing multiple `0`'s.

Comment: Nice work ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: What is the Trouble exactley ?

Comment: @DoHe Oh my former explanation for the "trouble" is wrong, see my edit.

Comment: "MATLAB doesn't have implicit time sign" - right, it has to explicitly use `.*` to multiply stuff. That's the thing with language design, it's full of compromises. If you want to allow space as a separator, then you can't multiply two variables with a space; if you want to be able to multiply things like `x y`, then you need to delimit your arrays differently.

Comment: @J.M Thank a lot for the explenation of the Problem with the space seperator.

Answer (score 9):

One idea is to use a style sheet to enable MATLAB-type matrix input. The following is an extension of @xzczd's idea. Here is the style sheet:

```
Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["MATLAB", StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Input"]],

        (* Use a private context so that $Line doesn't increment during processing *)
        CellContext->Cell,

        (* Add a tag to the evaluation cell, and hence to its generated cells *)
        CellProlog:>SetOptions[EvaluationCell[],CellTags->"MATLAB"],

        (* Clear tags *)
        CellEpilog:>(SetOptions[#1,CellTags->{}]&)/@Cells[CellTags->"MATLAB"],
        CellEvaluationFunction->Function[
            Module[{m},
                ToExpression[
                    # //.  RowBox[{"[", b__}] -> RowBox[{ToString[m],"[",b}],
                    StandardForm,
                    Function[Null,
                        Defer@@(Hold[#1]
                            //.  {
                                m[a_CompoundExpression] :> With[
                                    {tmp = Replace[Defer[a], {CompoundExpression->List,Times->List}, 3, Heads->True]},
                                    tmp/;True
                                ],
                                m[a_]:>With[{tmp=Replace[Defer[a], {Times->List}, 2, Heads->True]}, tmp/;True]
                                }
                            //.  Defer[x_]:>x),
                        HoldAll
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],

        (* MATInput style looks like input, but it has a working CellAutoOverwrite option *)
        System`GeneratedCellStyles->{"Output"->"MATInput"},

        (* No need to show In for this cell *)
        ShowCellLabel->False,

        (* Make the cell look like text *)
        FontFamily->"Arial",
        FontSize->14,
        FontWeight->"Plain",
        AutoMultiplicationSymbol->False
    ],
    Cell[StyleData["MATInput", StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Output"]],

        (* Convert to regular Input cell before evaluation *)
        CellProlog:>SetOptions[EvaluationCell[],CellStyle->"Input"],

        (* Disappear if the MATLAB cell generating the MATInput is reevaluated *)
        GeneratedCell->True,
        CellAutoOverwrite->True,

        (* No need to show cell label until after it is converted to an Input cell *)
        ShowCellLabel->False,

        (* Make it look like an Input cell*)
        ShowStringCharacters->True,
        NumberMarks->True,
        FontWeight->"DemiBold"
    ]
    },
    WindowSize->{808,689},
    WindowMargins->{{Automatic,274},{28,Automatic}},
    FrontEndVersion->"10.3 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel) (December 10, 2015)",
    StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
];
NotebookPut @ %;
```

Here is how it works. The following is a MATLAB-style cell:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 ; 2 3 4 5 6^2]
```

After evaluation of the above cell, we have the original MATLAB cell and a generated MATInput cell:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 ; 2 3 4 5 6^2]
```

> a={{1,2,3,4,5},{2,3,4,5,6^2}}

If we edit the MATLAB cell, and then reevaluate, the old generated MATInput cell is overwritten by the new MATInput cell. Also, note that the generated cell hasn't evaluated, 6^2 is not 36 yet, and a has no OwnValue:

```
OwnValues[a]
```

> {}

If we select the generated cell and evaluate it, then everything works as expected:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6^2}}
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 36}}

Note that the above "Input" cell has now become a real Input cell, and will no longer be overwritten when the MATLAB cell that generated it is reevaluated.

So, the work flow is to create a MATLAB cell, populate it with a MATLAB-style matrix, and then evaluate the MATLAB cell to generate the equivalent unevaluated Mathematica Input cell. This Input cell can then be evaluated to generate results.

Some advantages of this approach are that the MATLAB cell can contain arbitrary Mathematica code, and you can use `CompoundExpression` and `Times` in the matrix entries since they are only replaced at the top levels. For example, @xzczd's problematic examples can be handled as follows:

```
[Times[a b] ; c (d e)]
```

> {{a b},{c,d e}}

```
[Times[i = 1 ; i + 1]]
```

> {i=1;i+1}

Comment: (+1) I did, or at least started, something like this, but didn't solve the parsing-expressions-as-entries problem. Given both [``MATLink` ``](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/calling-matlab-from-mathematica/24478#24478) and Control-comma/return, it seemed just an academic exercise, anyway, and I stopped. Still an interesting answer.

Comment: BTW don't you want `RuleDelayed` to localize the pattern name `b` inside `ToExpression[]` in the `CellEvaluationFunction`?

Comment: To avoid situations like `b=3; 5 /. b_->b` returning 3 instead of the expected 5? Using `CellContext->Cell` prevents the possibility of b having `OwnValues`, so I think it's a matter of taste whether to use `Rule` or `RuleDelayed` here.

Comment: I see. I missed that. Thanks. It was just the question of `b` having a global value. So does `m` need to be localized? Or is it just the `Temporary` attribute? (I like the `m` trick, because I struggled with that problem.)

Answer (score 6):

An alternative answer to what Feyre suggested using strings:

```
stringToMatrix[string_] :=
string // StringSplit[#, ";"] & // Map[StringSplit[#, " " ] &] //ToExpression

stringToMatrix["1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9"]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}} *)
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Suppose the number of data are a multiple of 4. This is a simple way

```
m = HoldForm[{1 2 3 4, 5 6 7 8, 9 10 11 12}] /. 
  a_ b_ c_ d_ -> {a, b, c, d}
```

Try

```
m//MatrixForm
```

this doesn't work since the HoldForm must be release.

```
 mm = ReleaseHold[mm]
```

and now the precedent command works

If you want a $3 \times 4$ matrix

```
mmm = Partition[Flatten[mm], 3]
```

It's the simplest way I can imagine