# Convert Fortran-like number form to traditional number form

Tags: conversion, fortran

What is the most elegant way to convert arbitrary numbers written as (verbatim):

```
1.13903 e - 08
```

into traditional *Mathematica* number form without having to convert the number into text (string), performing text substitutions, and so on?

(Of course `1.13903 e - 08` is $1.13903 \cdot 10^{-8}$.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closest to sensible I can imagine would be wrapping these numbers individually with a function if e is always followed by sign (`+`or `-`):

```
ClearAll@fn;
fn[m_. e + e_] := m 10^e;
fn[m_. e] := m;
fn[_] := 0;

fn[1.13903 e - 08]
```

> 1.13903*10^-8

Handling the case where `+` is implicit seems awfully convoluted to get right.

I also thought of redefining `e` as an operator, but firstly I don't think arbitrary letters can be redefined that way, and secondly all hell would probably break loose if such a definition would be present globally.

Comment: Yes... this works, and certainly along my initial efforts.  Thanks.  I was hoping for some clever option for `NumberForm` but this will do.  ($\checkmark$)

Comment: But it actually works in this form only if your have + or - after `e`! I'll try to work a little more on it.

Comment: `HoldAll` will help you handling `4 e 5` :) .

Comment: @xzczd I tried it and failed to make it work in a sensible manner. Probably worth a second answer. In particular, ordering changes seem to occur depending on values of mantissa and exponent.

Comment: That should not happen. `Orderless` doesn't start up in a function with `HoldAll` attribute. See my answer for more info.

Comment: @xzczd Stupid trouble on my code, as I stated on comment to your answer.

Answer (score 7):

An enhanced version of [kirma's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221318/1871), which handles expressions like `5 e 4`:

```
ClearAll@fn;
SetAttributes[fn, HoldAll]
fn[m_. e + e_] := m 10^e
fn[a_. e b_] := a 10^b

fn[5 e 4]
(* 50000 *)
```

Comment: Hah! I tested my function... having wrong definition overriding the one I was attempting to test in the front of tests being run. Now I understand why it didn't work. :)

Answer (score 3):

you are fighting with windmills.

```
   Interpreter["Number"]["4.5E-7"]
```

gives you `4.5*10^-7`

Comment: But OP mentions that he doesn't want to "convert the number into text (string)". And for that case, I'll use [`Internal\`StringToDouble`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1744/1871).

Comment: @xzczd, How can you import arbitrary number to MMa? I know two ways - read from file and from shared memory. Both of them mean interpretation of textual or binary data. However, the form like xxE-yy is direct pointer to the textual data isn't it?

Comment: One possibility is, OP just want to type numbers using the `e` notation. Similar question comes up before: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135867/1871

Comment: But `Interpreter["Number"]["1.13903 e - 08"]` returns a Failure.

Comment: @corey979, I guess due to the spaces

Comment: @Rom38:  It is a clever idea, but alas doesn't work for my case, as corey979 points out.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Even then, the most _practical_ solution is probably `Interpreter["Number"][StringDelete["1.13903 e - 08", " "]]`, even if it does technically "perform a text substitution".