# how can I type brackets for column vectors?

Tags: formatting

My goal is to type $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}$ in mathematica. I try {a,b,c} but i am not sure if it will be converted to the corrected output.

Comment: Related: [(761)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/761/121),
[(17004)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17004/121), [(41804)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41804/121),
[(55990)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55990/121) (the last one may be a duplicate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enter a column or matrix by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to add rows or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to add columns.  (You can do this anywhere in the Notebook; you do not need to somehow generate a matrix beforehand.)  The small empty squares are [`\[Placeholder]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Placeholder.html) and you can move between them using <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.  You can optionally wrap the column or matrix with `(` and `)` and they will be vertically stretched to fit.

[image]

For more methods and examples see these tutorials:

- [Entering Tables and Matrices](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EnteringTablesAndMatrices.html)
- [How to | Input a Matrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/InputAMatrix.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
m = {{a},{b},{c}};
m // MatrixForm
```